# validate all arrayitems except last in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

With the asterisk I can validate all array items, like this:

```
'event_time_start.*' => 'required|date_format:G:i',
```

But I want apply this validation rule on all items, except the last one. How can I achive this?

Comment: Size of the array is constant or variable ?

Comment: It is Variable  .

Comment: Can you explain the reason behind neglecting validation for last element of array :D

Comment: In the interface, the user can make a new row. To accomplisch this, I have hide the last row, and clone this row. But the inputs of the hidden row are also send, so I need to skip this in de validation.

Comment: So, empty value goes as input in the array am I right ?

Comment: yes that is right

Comment: have you tried with `sometimes` validation like, `'event_time_start.*' => 'sometimes|date_format:G:i',` ?

Comment: That won't work. The last value is always present but empty.

Comment: But I can fix something in the html/javascript. But I was hoping there was an easy solution in the validator.

Comment: Then okay nice question :D

Comment: You can create a [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#custom-validation-rules) and pass the array `event_time_start`. Then the validation will look like `'event_time_start' => [new EventTimeStart]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always recommended to exclude unnecessory item from front end if possible. If not you can remove last item before sending request data to `Validator`.

```
    $requestData = $request->all();
    $count = count($requestData["event_time_start"]);
    unset($requestData["event_time_start"][$count-1]);
    $validator = Validator::make( $requestData  , [
        'event_time_start.*' => 'required',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript, you're cloning an empty hidden row when a user clicks add. My solution would be to not have a `name` attribute on that field, so it is never posted to the server. When you clone the row, then add the `name="event_time_start[]"` attribute to the newly cloned row.

This would preserve bandwidth and allow you to not need the squirrelly validator exception, which will be strange to read in code 6 months from now.